# ARM64 architecture (M1 chip): Cannot install pg gem (using PostgresApp)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, pg, apple-silicon, postgresapp

I've been trying to install a rails project on my computer (Macbook Pro 2020 with M1) running Big Sur.

I have the PostgresApp installed.

When running `bundle install` it fails to build the `pg` gem so I tried to install the gem manually (by doing `gem install pg` - tried also with `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin/pg_config`).

I get an error saying:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

When checking the error logs I see:

```
have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no

ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/lib/libpq.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-db479f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
 4:
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12:
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))PQconnectdb; return !p; }
/* end */
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you need to use Postgres.app? I ran into the same issue. I deleted it and used a homebrew version of postgres. Works well.

Comment: @IngmarasKeleras yes, the native version has some collation issues in MacOS.

Answer (score 88):

For those who are just trying to install the pg gem and don't care about PostgresApp, the key to fixing pg on the M1 is ensuring the existence of the `libpq`. These steps allowed me to get the pg gem install on my M1 mac without resorting to using x86 version or build flags:

```
brew install libpq
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"
gem install pg
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me! Agree it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me on M1 pro

Comment: This is not optimum as it skips Postgres.app, but going back to x86 homebrew seems insane to me. I don't see myself doing this without having to deal with other numerous compatibility issues. But I may be wrong. It feels extreme anyway.

Comment: Freaking genius.

Comment: This was very helpful, but homebrew has recently changed postgresql installation, using explicit version tags, so installing libpq with brew didn't help--- it didn't know where my "real" postgresql installation was. I had to find my real pg_config file and add the path to there: `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin:$PATH"`. Then I had to specify pg version 1.4.3 in my Gemfile and bundle install.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem with M1 + the ruby pg gem.  The problem was that I had a mix of ARM + x86 binaries on my system, and `pg` apparently can only be compiled with x86 at present.  As FYI, there are new issues reported in its github repo, so hopefully it'll be solved soon [here](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/367)

My work around:

0. uninstall ARM based homebrew + rbenv and remove your `.gem` + `.rbenv` directories from your home dir ([homebrew uninstall instructions](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew))
1. re-install homebrew as x86 intel-based

```
$ arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

2. install rbenv as x86 (or whatever your preferred ruby version manager)

```
$ arch -x86_64 brew install rbenv
$ arch -x86_64 rbenv install 2.7.2
```

3a) (optional) for postgres.app, you can pre-configure where pg-config lives so you don't have to run the manual gem install when it chokes.  eg

```
$ bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
```

3b) (optional) for brew, you can do the same:

```
$ bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=$(brew --prefix)/opt/libpq/bin/pg_config
```

4. re-bundle your project and enjoy ruby on rosetta 2 (for now)

```
$ bundle install
$ rails s
```

Comment: I ended up installing the native postgres (didn't want ruby to run "emulated" for performance issues). I'll wait until postgres.app releases an ARM64 version :)

Comment: @Tiago I asked a question about this hoping that I didn't have to resort to install postgres using homebrew. I guess I will do the same. My current instance is on a 10-year-old High Sierra computer so I want to move to it to my M1 computer.

Comment: Postgres.app now released a beta arm version available here: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/releases/tag/v2.5beta1, the pg gem now installs with it!

Answer (score 5):

Encountered the same issue with brew PostgreSQL, but I installed pg gem successfully with Ruby 2.7 on macOS M1(12 Monterey), I have both x86 and arm64 brew installed. Since pg must be compiled with x86 libpq, so I installed libpq with x86 brew

```
❯ which brow
brow: aliased to arch --x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew

❯ brow install libpq

❯ brew install PostgreSQL # Install arm64 PostgreSQL 
❯ brew services start postgresql
❯ ps -ef | grep postgresql
  501 23655     1   0  2:29PM ??         0:00.10 /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres

❯ which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
❯ brew -v
Homebrew 3.3.2-50-geca16a2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision ec99d74792c; last commit 2021-11-05)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 2ab51af9c3; last commit 2021-11-05)
```

Then I can install the pg gem

```
❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]

❯ gem install pg -v 1.2.3 -- --with-pq-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.3
Building native extensions with: '--with-pq-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.3'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.2.3
Parsing documentation for pg-1.2.3
Done installing documentation for pg after 0 seconds
```

But failed with Ruby 2.6, I don't know why

```
gem install pg -v 1.2.3 -- --with-pq-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.3
Building native extensions with: '--with-pq-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.3'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/Users/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20211105-41969-1oxcuyy.rb extconf.rb --with-pq-dir\=/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.3
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /opt/homebrew/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
```

#### Update 2021-11-06

Installed pg successfully with Ruby 2.6 too.

1. First  install x86 postgresql

```
# build Postgresql from source, as 
# Error: postgresql: no bottle available! 
# You can try to install from source with:  
# brew install --build-from-source postgresql


brow install --build-from-source postgresql
```

2. Install pg gem with prefix

```
gem install pg -v 1.2.3 -- --with-pg_config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.3/bin/pg_config --with-pq-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.3
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I was looking all over for a solution to this and it was `brew install PostgreSQL` that allowed me to run `gem install pg` without errors.