# Installing pg -v 1.2.3 using ARCHFLAGS on mac chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

## Summary of the problem

I'm following some setup instructions that has this step:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v 1.2.3
```

problem appears to be related to the fact that I'm running a MacBookPro with an M1 chip, per [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908116/correct-archflags-value-on-apple-silicon)

the expected result is presumably a successfully installed pg gem (version 1.2.3)

Instead, I'm seeing errors that I believe are related to the different file paths that are used between Intel and Apple silicon.

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for PQsslAttribute()... yes
checking for PQresultVerboseErrorMessage()... yes
checking for PQencryptPasswordConn()... yes
checking for PQresultMemorySize()... yes
checking for timegm()... yes
checking for rb_gc_adjust_memory_usage()... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230720-5310-17fm3z sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230720-5310-17fm3z clean

current directory: /Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230720-5310-17fm3z sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230720-5310-17fm3z
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
In file included from gvl_wrappers.c:6:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg.c
In file included from pg.c:49:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
In file included from pg_binary_decoder.c:8:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
In file included from pg_binary_encoder.c:7:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_coder.c
In file included from pg_coder.c:6:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/core/rstring.h:52:27: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
#define RSTRING_LEN       RSTRING_LEN
                          ^
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_connection.c
In file included from pg_connection.c:7:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
pg_connection.c:679:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return INT2NUM(atol(port));
               ~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
In file included from pg_copy_coder.c:6:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/core/rstring.h:52:27: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
#define RSTRING_LEN       RSTRING_LEN
                          ^
pg_copy_coder.c:534:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                input_len = end_ptr - start_ptr;
                          ~ ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
compiling pg_errors.c
In file included from pg_errors.c:6:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_record_coder.c
In file included from pg_record_coder.c:6:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/core/rstring.h:52:27: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
#define RSTRING_LEN       RSTRING_LEN
                          ^
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_result.c
In file included from pg_result.c:7:
In file included from ./pg.h:61:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:85:5: warning: 'SIZEOF_VOID_P' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if SIZEOF_VOID_P >= 8
    ^
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/include/pg_config_manual.h:168:5: warning: 'HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if HAVE_DECL_POSIX_FADVISE && defined(HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE)
    ^
pg_result.c:1006:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return INT2NUM(n);
               ~~~~~~~ ^
pg_result.c:1590:58: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cData'
        rb_cPGresult = rb_define_class_under( rb_mPG, "Result", rb_cData );
                                                                ^
3 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [pg_result.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/JRBOBDOBBS/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-20/3.2.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out
```

## What I've tried:

1. per the article I linked above, I tried this:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch $(uname -m)" gem install pg -v 1.2.3
```

Which I thought was a pretty slick improvisation; alas, no dice

2. the same thing, but without the interpolation

I considered just foregoing the `ARCHFLAGS` bit, because at the end of the day, isn't this simply attempting to install the 1.2.3 version of pg?

## My question(s)

*What's the proper, unambiguous command for using the `ARCHFLAGS` variable on a MacBookPro with M1 chip?*

Or maybe more to the point:

*Do I even need to fuss with that ARCHFLAGS variable?*

#### Edit 1:

I found [this solution to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70316977/8659405) and went through the steps there:

```
brew install libpq
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH
gem install pg
```

and it installed succesfully, but that was pg -v 1.5.3
(does it really matter if I use -v 1.2.3?)

Comment: Having libpq is the right way to do this, and no - no reason to use less than the latest `pg` unless you have a specific reason to do so (eg. an old/legacy project).

Comment: Ok, I seem to have been able to move beyond this issue using this fix. Should I delete this question? Or do you want to move your comment to an actual answer? Or should I edit my question?

Comment: Added as an answer, not sure how generally applicable this will be, but no harm in having your working through the problem saved for googlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `libpq` is the right way to do this, and no - no reason to use less than the latest `pg` unless you have a specific reason to do so (eg. an old/legacy project).

Also, as I think you realized, based on your `ARCHFLAGS="-arch $(uname -m)"` example (which is very nifty), using the x86 flags for an amd64 chip (ie. Mac M1/M2) is never going to work.